# iPhone 3GS - can't ever seem to hold 60fps with CADisplayLink

Tags: iphone, game-loop

So I've switched from `NSTimer` to `CADisplayLink` and I'm still seeing unexpected variation in my frame counter - it fluctuates between 59-60fps, even when I'm not rendering much.

Has anyone else seen this? Is this an expected variation in iOS? Or should I look more closely at my game loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience this is normal behavior. The measured time can change slightly and if 59.99 FPS are calculated and you output that with just 2 digits, it's going to show 59.

Don't worry about fluctuations of one frame.

Comment: Ok - I was outputting XX.XX digits but it flickers too quick for me to see, and I didn't bother tracking min/max value. If other people see this then I'm happy.